# How do I convert date and time string(1975-07-14T16:32:47.000Z) to Day-Month name-Year (14 July 1975) format in python

Tags: python

I am writing a UI automated test that checks a date in the database and returns the date as a string in this format 1975-07-14T16:32:47.000Z and comparing it to the date that is displayed on the webpage but the date on the webpage is in this format Day-Month name-Year (14 July 1975), therefore I need to convert the date return by the database to Day-Month name-Year (14 July 1975) so that I am comparing like for like. How do I change the date string to the format I need

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dateutil.parser` to parse the string you got from the datebase into a `datetime.datetime`, which in turn can be formatted using `strftime`:

```
import dateutil.parser

input="1975-07-14T16:32:47.000Z"

dt = dateutil.parser.parse(input)

print(dt.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
```

Comment: For requested formatting, you can use `print(dt.strftime("%d %B %Y"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_string = "1975-07-14T16:32:47.000Z"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(dt_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
new_datetime_string = datetime.strftime(datetime_object, "%d-%B-%Y")
print(new_datetime_string)
# prints "14-July-1975"
```

We are using datetime module where `datetime.strptime` will generate a datetime object where you can call `.date()`,`.time()`,`.today()` and other functions but to get back to string as per the given format of **Day-Month Name-Year** `datetime.strftime()`(stringify time) is used. This converts datetime obj to given format of datetime string.

- %d - date (DD - 01,02,...,31)
- %m - month (MM - 01,02,...,12)
- %Y - Year (YYYY - 2022,2021,...)
- %B - Full Month Name (January, Feburary,..)
- %f - Milliseconds

you can find out more in following link: [Datetime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)